# What is the Difference Between Dedicated Hosts and Dedicated Instances on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm new to AWS, Please help me in understanding with practical example and if possible with architectural diagram.
Appreciate your help in advance

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/808706/what-is-the-difference-between-an-amazon-dedicated-instance-and-a-dedicated-host

Answer (score 11):

A dedicated host runs dedicated instances. A dedicated host is a physical server "owned" by you and only instance that you own run on this host. In the regular AWS environment, you do not have control over the host that an instance runs on and instances from other companies could be running on the same host.

Dedicated Hosts cost more and you pay for them even when they are not used.

Dedicated Hosts and Instances are typically used when a company has very tight security requirements, or has software licensing requirements where the license is attached to hardware or needs fine grained control over what runs on a host.

[Amazon EC2 Dedicated Hosts](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/)

Comment: Thanks for the answering quickly but just side question that when an architect design he keeps in mind about Edge location, AZ, nearest Region,  scalability etc. so what about in dedicated host? Please correct me if my question is not applicable for dedicate host. Thanks in advance

Comment: Dedicated hosts are allocated in a specific Region and AZ that you select. Edge locations don't apply to EC2 instances (that is a cloudfront concept). Scalability is controlled by you using normal AWS services such as ASG (Auto Scaling Groups). Keep in mind if you need fault tolerance across AZs then you will need more than one Dedicated Host in different AZs.

Answer (score 1):

When you want greater control over the application resources, you use dedicated hosts.
ex. when greater security is required, then implement your own resources required for your application. Since the dedicated physical servers in the data centers have no tenancy, you have the full control over it, but you pay for it even when you're not using it. It's more suitable for a firm application usage which doesn't have interruptions, and cost is not really a big deal.
(please update if anything has been recently changed in this service.)

Now for the difference in dedicated hosts and dedicated instances,

1. Certainly the billing is for host vs for (an) instance.
2. Visibility of sockets, cores, and host ID is missing from an instance ofc.
3. Bring Your Own License (BYOL) is a unique feature of DH.
4. However, one point that On Demand DHs can't assume is the capacity reservations. Meaning, since the pricing, usage, sockets etc. are limited (until you pay for more), you can't apply the reservation principle of cutting usage and costs. (Alert! Disambiguation - DH and OD-DH)

For more info, check out
[Dedicated Hosts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/dedicated-hosts-overview.html)